# "missing required gems" error when creating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

When I run

```
$ sudo RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

> missing these required gems:
>
> ```
> rubytree  >= 0
> ```
>
> You're running:
>
> ```
>    ruby 1.8.7.249 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8  
>    rubygems 1.8.15 at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8, /home/venkat/.gem/ruby/1.8
> ```
>
> Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
>   venkat@ubuntu:/var/redmine$ sudo vi config/database.yml

When I try to install the `rubytree` gem I get the following error:

> gem install rubytree --version ">= 0" ERROR: While generating documentation for rubytree-0.8.2 ... MESSAGE: exit ... RDOC args: --ri --op /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rubytree-0.8.2/ri --files COPYING,API-CHANGES --title Rubytree Documentation --quiet lib History.txt Manifest.txt COPYING API-CHANGES --title rubytree-0.8.2 Documentation --quiet

Comment: so doesn't `rake gems:install` help?

Comment: gem install rubytree --version ">= 0"
ERROR:  While generating documentation for rubytree-0.8.2
... MESSAGE:   exit
... RDOC args: --ri --op /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rubytree-0.8.2/ri --files COPYING,API-CHANGES --title Rubytree Documentation --quiet lib History.txt Manifest.txt COPYING API-CHANGES --title rubytree-0.8.2 Documentation --quiet

Comment: I don't mean to be "that guy" but is there some reason why you aren't using the newest versions of Ruby (> 1.9.3) and Rails (> 3.1)? You'd be surprised how many issues can be resolved by upgrading to latest versions. Try it!

Comment: try `gem install rubytree --no-ri --no-rdoc`, looks like you're having problems with doc installation

Comment: gem install rubytree --no-ri --no-rdoc it doesn't show any error but when i run one more command "RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:load_default_data" it giving same error

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with redmine and the versions of ruby/rubygems. It doesn't detect rubytree, even though it is already installed or exists in vendor directory. See redmine issues [#9815](http://www.redmine.org/issues/9815) and [#9798](http://www.redmine.org/issues/9798).

You can fix this by updating redmine to the current trunk or by making the changes from [revision 8214](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/8214).

Comment: thaks that is the only problem